# Python multiprocessing pool; wait for iteration to complete

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I've got a large dataset which I want my script to iterate through, perform a series of operations on each entry, then arrange the results for storage to HDD. Because the datasets can be relatively large (~250 GB), RAM availability requires that the dataset be processed in chunks (what I've called dataBlock in the code below) of 1000 entries at a time. I also use the `multiprocessing.Pool` class to facilitate use of multiple CPU cores for this task.

I've essentially got things arranged so that each dataBlock is passed to the Pool, the Pool executes the desired calculations on the dataBlock using the `imap` method, the Pool returns the calculation results, and the results for the data chunk are appended to a list. This list (`processed_data`) is the desired end product of the set of calculations.

```
processed_data = []

multiprocessing.Pool(processor_cap) as pool:

    for blockIndex, block in enumerate(range(1000, height-remainder, 1000)):

        #Read-in 1000 spectra from source dataset
        dataBlock = np.asarray(raw_dset[blockIndex*1000:block][:])

        '''
        Pass data block to processor pool, which iterates through data
        block. Each spectrum is handed off to a CPU in the pool,
        which centroids it and appends the result to "processed_block".
        '''
        processed_block = pool.imap(centroid_spectrum, dataBlock)

        #Append processed spectra to processed data bin
        for idx, processed_spectrum in enumerate(processed_block):
            processed_data.append(processed_spectrum)
```

What I'd like to know is how to make the script pause after the call of `pool.imap()` until the full `processed_block` has been returned without closing the pool. Currently, it progresses right into the `for` loop which immediately follows in the snippit above without waiting for `processed_block` to be returned by `pool.imap`. I've tried calling `pool.join()` immediately after the `pool.imap()` call, but it only returns `***AssertionError` and again continues to the `for` loop below it. I can eventually successfully call `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` later in the script once all dataBlocks have been fed to the pool, just below the end of the outermost `for` loop above.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Have you tried `map` instead of `imap`?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, I need to use `imap` because the order `processed_block` is very important.

Comment: `Pool.map` preserves order of the jobs

Comment: I was under the impression that it did not, but reading the documentation a little more carefully it seems I misunderstood. I'm trying `map` again right now, so far without problems. I've made some major edits to the rest of the script since I last tried it, so my earlier problems with `map` may have been due to bugs elsewhere. I'll update tomorrow when it's had time to fully execute.

Comment: The script executed as intended using `map` instead of `imap`. I have no idea why `map` was not working previously, but it is definitely doing what I want it to now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed the `Pool.imap()` call to a `Pool.map()` call, and the script ran as intended. See my exchange with [Mikhail Burshteyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5030758/mikhail-burshteyn) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to work with your example, without a lot of effort to change things around; but if you have an Iterator from the imap() call, then you might consider resolving the element of the iterator to a list before you reach the for loop:

```
processed_block = pool.imap(centroid_spectrum, dataBlock)
processed_block = [ x for x in processed_block ] # convert from an iterator to a list
for idx, processed_spectrum in enumerate(processed_block):
```

etc.

Does that achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Just use `pool.map` instead